# How to test blinking element of a web page?

Tags: testing, web, selenium-webdriver

Suppose that you have a web page with blinking elements  (for instance the background of a cell blinks red when a condition happen on the database, the page queries the database with a javascript).  How would you verify that the element is blinking with Selenium web driver?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if element is visible or not.

```
IWebElement myBlink = chrome.FindElement(By.Id("blink"));
if (myBlink.Displayed)
{
      //it's displayed
}
else
{
      //it's not displayed
}
```

All you have to do next is create a timer to set up time when to check it again.